# using PHP with Composer did not find the required Class

Tags: php, class, pdf, composer-php

I've got a PHP code that selects a PDF file and converts it to a text file.

I'm using an external library **pdf-to-text** with the composer.

Following is the system display error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Pdf' not found in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\testcomposer\test2.php:6 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\testcomposer\test2.php on line 6

## Project Structure :

- testcomposer

  - app

    ```
    -Spatie
       -pdftotext
          -src
            -Exceptions
              -CouldNotExtractText.php
              -PdfNotFound.php
            -pdf.php
    -symfony
    ```
  - vendor

    ```
    -composer
    -autoload.php
    ```
  - composer.json
  - test2.php
  - xxx.pdf

## codes

## pdf.php

```
<?php

namespace Spatie\pdftotext\src;

use Spatie\pdftotext\src\Exceptions;
use Symfony\process;

class Pdf
{
    protected $pdf;

    protected $binPath;

    public function __construct(string $binPath = null)
    {
        $this->binPath = $binPath ?? '/usr/bin/pdftotext';
    }

    public function setPdf(string $pdf) : Pdf
    {
        if (!file_exists($pdf)) {
            throw new PdfNotFound("could not find pdf {$pdf}");
        }

        $this->pdf = $pdf;

        return $this;
    }

    public function text() : string
    {
        $process = new Process("{$this->binPath} " . escapeshellarg($this->pdf) . " -");
        $process->run();

        if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
            throw new CouldNotExtractText($process);
        }

        return trim($process->getOutput(), " \t\n\r\0\x0B\x0C");
    }

    public static function getText(string $pdf, string $binPath = null) : string
    {
        return (new static($binPath))
            ->setPdf($pdf)
            ->text();
    }
}
```

## composer.json

```
{
    "name": "spatie/pdf-to-text",
    "description": "Extract text from a pdf",
    "keywords": [
        "spatie",
        "pdftotext"
    ],
    "homepage": "https://github.com/spatie/pdf-to-text",
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Freek Van der Herten",
            "email": "freek@spatie.be",
            "homepage": "https://spatie.be",
            "role": "Developer"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php" : "^7.0",
        "symfony/process": "^3.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit" : "^6.4"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "src\\": "app/Spatie/pdftotext/src"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Spatie\\pdftotext\\Test\\": "tests"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "test": "phpunit"
    }
}
```

## test2.php

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Spatie\pdftotext\src;
$text = (new Pdf())
    ->setPdf('اجواء.pdf')
    ->text();
?>
```

Comment: What a mess, the namespace is `\Spatie\PdfToText\Pdf`. RTM: https://github.com/spatie/pdf-to-text

Comment: You dont change the vendors composer file.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone i tried to use it as it is but did not work so i was trying to do some changes in order to work in my project structure

Comment: @LawrenceCherone so can you help me to fix this problem i have been struggling with this error

Comment: @Georges have you tried using the *proper* namespace?

Comment: Can you change namespace of pdf.php to "namespace src"
and change use in test2.php to "use src\Pdf;"