# how to fix the error displayed by the PHP code?

Tags: php, class, pdf

this question is the continues of this [last question with different error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47694146/using-php-with-composer-did-not-find-the-required-class) 
I've got a PHP code that selects a PDF file and converts it to a text file.

I'm using an external library **pdf-to-text** with the composer.

Following is the system display error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Spatie\PdfToText\Exceptions\CouldNotExtractText:
>   The command "/usr/bin/pdftotext "pdf.pdf" -" failed. Exit Code:
>   1(General error) Working directory: C:\xampp\htdocs\testcomposer
>   Output: ================ Error Output: ================ The system
>   cannot find the path specified. in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\testcomposer\src\Pdf.php:37 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\testcomposer\test2.php(8):
>   Spatie\PdfToText\Pdf->text() #1 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\testcomposer\src\Pdf.php on line 37

## Project Structure :

- testcomposer

  - src

    ```
      -Exceptions
           -CouldNotExtractText.php
           -PdfNotFound.php
      -pdf.php
    ```
  - vendor

    ```
    -composer
    -autoload.php
    ```
  - `composer.json`
  - `test2.php`
  - `pdf.php`

## codes

## pdf.php

```
<?php

namespace Spatie\pdftotext\src;

use Spatie\pdftotext\src\Exceptions;
use Symfony\process;

class Pdf
{
    protected $pdf;

    protected $binPath;

    public function __construct(string $binPath = null)
    {
        $this->binPath = $binPath ?? '/usr/bin/pdftotext';
    }

    public function setPdf(string $pdf) : Pdf
    {
        if (!file_exists($pdf)) {
            throw new PdfNotFound("could not find pdf {$pdf}");
        }

        $this->pdf = $pdf;

        return $this;
    }

    public function text() : string
    {
        $process = new Process("{$this->binPath} " . escapeshellarg($this->pdf) . " -");
        $process->run();

        if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
            throw new CouldNotExtractText($process);
        }

        return trim($process->getOutput(), " \t\n\r\0\x0B\x0C");
    }

    public static function getText(string $pdf, string $binPath = null) : string
    {
        return (new static($binPath))
            ->setPdf($pdf)
            ->text();
    }
}
```

## composer.json

```
{
    "name": "spatie/pdf-to-text",
    "description": "Extract text from a pdf",
    "keywords": [
        "spatie",
        "pdftotext"
    ],
    "homepage": "https://github.com/spatie/pdf-to-text",
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Freek Van der Herten",
            "email": "freek@spatie.be",
            "homepage": "https://spatie.be",
            "role": "Developer"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php" : "^7.0",
        "symfony/process": "^3.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit" : "^6.4"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "src\\": "app/Spatie/pdftotext/src"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Spatie\\pdftotext\\Test\\": "tests"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "test": "phpunit"
    }
}
```

## test2.php

```
    <?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Spatie\PdfToText\Pdf;

$text = (new Pdf())
    ->setPdf('pdf.pdf')
    ->text();

print_r($text);
?>
```

Comment: To point to the real problem: `$process->isSuccessful()` returns false

Comment: Do you have this path: `'/usr/bin/pdftotext'` (from constructor)

Comment: @Justinas no i do not have this path.... i mentioned in my question the project structure

Answer (score 0):

I create test project for get content from pdf file
check this git

https://github.com/akkapong/test-pdf

the package pdf-to-text you use is required pdftotext command so you need to install first.

after you install the command will tell you about path of command 
you can replace the path in file test.php on line 6

================== run test.php =================
$ php test.php

hope this help

Comment: where to find the package **pdftotext command ** i am using windows 7 is this a problem ??

Comment: ftp://ftp.gnome.org/Public/GNOME/binaries/win32/dependencies/ 
find for poppler

Comment: @ Akkapong Kajornwongwattana I DID NOT understand your answer

Comment: click this link
ftp://ftp.gnome.org/Public/GNOME/binaries/win32/dependencies/poppler-0.6.4.zip

unzip and install file dll 
https://lifehacker.com/269063/install-a-dll-file-in-windows
look this link for more information